# SwiftUI TextEditor Scroll with Show Keyboard Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application with SwiftUI lifecycle that uses TextFields and
TextEditors. I have written a modifier to deal with scrolling the content that would
be underneath the keyboard when the keyboard is present. My modifier works as expected
for TextFields but not at all for TextEditors. The Apple docs say the
keyboardWillShowNotification is
posted immediately prior to the display of the keyboard. I cannot find anything which
states the notification is limited to only TextFields. Both field types are in the same ScrollView. Hopefully I'm missing
something simple here.

My modifier:

```
struct AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard: ViewModifier {

    @State var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, self.currentHeight)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(self.currentHeight == 0 ? Edge.Set() : .bottom)
            .onAppear(perform: subscribeToKeyboardEvents)
    }

    private let keyboardWillOpen = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
        .map { $0.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect }
        .map { $0.height }

    private let keyboardWillHide =  NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
        .map { _ in CGFloat.zero }

    private func subscribeToKeyboardEvents() {
        _ = Publishers.Merge(keyboardWillOpen, keyboardWillHide)
            .subscribe(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.self.currentHeight, on: self)
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode Version 12.2 beta (12B5018i) iOS 14

First edit: I thought the issue was likely a failure to receive notifications when the TextEditor receives the focus. However, adding this modifier to the TextEditor shows that the notification is fired. No progress:

```
   .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification)) { _ in
        print("Cursor is in TextEditor!")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you should store subscriber as below

```
struct AdaptsToSoftwareKeyboard: ViewModifier {

    @State var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var cancelable: AnyCancellable?
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, self.currentHeight)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(self.currentHeight == 0 ? Edge.Set() : .bottom)
            .onAppear(perform: subscribeToKeyboardEvents)
    }

    private let keyboardWillOpen = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
        .map { $0.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect }
        .map { $0.height }

    private let keyboardWillHide =  NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)
        .map { _ in CGFloat.zero }

    private func subscribeToKeyboardEvents() {
        self.cancelable = Publishers.Merge(keyboardWillOpen, keyboardWillHide)
            .subscribe(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.self.currentHeight, on: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I believe that is better, however it makes no difference to the performance. The view does not scroll. I'll write some code to capture the notification. The only conclusion I can reach is that the keyboardWillShowNotification is not fired with the TextEditor receives the focus.

Comment: Any luck resolving this?  I have the same problem in Xcode 12.4/iOS 14.4.2?

Comment: Same problem for iOS 15 / Xcode 13.1
Is there a way to adopt keyboard for TextEditor?